# How to override a dependency in go modules?

Tags: go, dependency-management, go-modules

In `dep` you have the option to override a dependency and have it point to a different repo for example in the following https://github.com/kubermatic/glog-logrus library one needs to add the following lines to the Gopkg.toml file:

```
[[override]]
  name = "github.com/golang/glog"
  source = "github.com/kubermatic/glog-logrus"
```

Then in the codebase you `import "github.com/golang/glog`. However, in go modules I don't see such an option? which leads me to think the only solution is to change the import to `github.com/kubermatic/glog-logrus`.

Thanks!

Comment: Use the "replace" directive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what the `replace` directive is for.

Quoting from wiki [Go 1.11 Modules: When should I use the replace directive?](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#when-should-i-use-the-replace-directive)

> The `replace` directive allows you to supply another import path that might be another module located in VCS (GitHub or elsewhere), or on your local filesystem with a relative or absolute file path. The new import path from the `replace` directive is used without needing to update the import paths in the actual source code.

So add this to the `go.mod` file of your main module:

```
replace (
    github.com/golang/glog => github.com/kubermatic/glog-logrus v0.0.0
)
```

You can also instruct the `go` tool to make this edit for you:

```
go mod edit -replace github.com/golang/glog=github.com/kubermatic/glog-logrus@v0.0.0
```

(Use the version you're interested in.)

After this when you import `github.com/golang/glog`, `github.com/kubermatic/glog-logrus` will be used (without having to change import statements).

Comment: I added `replace` directive for one of my local modules in my project, but when I make changes in that "replaced" module, those changes are not reflected during runtime of my project. Where does "replaced" directive look into? The actual source? Or the module's binary?